# JavaScript conversion of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that I am trying to convert to raw JavaScript. Can someone please help me convert the syntax or point me in the right direction to find the equivalent outcome?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myArr = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "states.xml", // change to full path of file on server
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml,
            complete: setupAC,
            failure: function (data) {
                alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
        });

        function parseXml (xml) {
            //find every query value
            $(xml).find("state").each(function () {
                myArr.push($(this).attr("label"));
            }); 
        }

        function setupAC () {
            $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#searchForm").submit();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *I have a jQuery script I'm trying to convert to raw JavaScript.* Why?

Comment: The `$.ajax` and XML processing stuff could easily be replaced (http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), but the `autocomplete()` [from jQueryUI] will be a major pain! It alone would be worth sticking with jQuery.

Comment: Are you looking for cross browser solution? what browsers you have to support? Do you need to support older browsers? IE <9

Comment: @MattBurland it is just for educational purposes. I am very fond of jQuery.

Comment: @vittore I am just wanting to learn the core language.

Comment: So again what you have tried

Comment: you should learn to write in binary too

Comment: I can point you in the direction: [jquery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacement for `$(document).ready(function () { . . . });`

*JavaScript:*

```
function setup () {
    // Put your code here
}
```

*On the body tag in your HTML:*

```
<body onload="setup()"> . . . </body>
```

### Replacement for `$ajax({ . . . });`

```
function callAjax(config) {
    var request;

    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

         for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch (e) { }
         } // end for
    }

    request.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;

    function ensureReadiness() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) { // Request complete
            if (request.status === 200) { // Success
                config.success();
            } else { // Failure
                config.failure();
            }
        }
    }

    request.open(config.type, config.url, config.asyc);
    request.send(config.data);
}
```

(credits: [code.tutplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855); [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/))